# ASP.Net MVC 3.0 onclick print a View?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, pretty-print

In my MVC 3.0 Application I have links at various place to call print function.

On click of this link it returns a view with all required data and format in it.

Now Instead of showing that view, I would like to directly print that view with out showing user. Is it possible?

How can i get this done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start printing a page, you can call `window.print()` in Javascript. You can bind this either to a button or a link or automatically call it on page load. The step to load a new view with a print version is not really necessary anymore as browsers support media queries and stylesheets specifically targeted at specific media.

Common operation is to use the normal stylesheets for browsers and have an additional stylesheet just for print use. This task of this extra stylesheet is only to hides elements that don't make sense on a printout (e.g. navigation) or to style or position some elements (e.g. logo) differently. This way you can use the same HTML / view for both viewing in the browser as printing.

You would load the two stylesheets like this:

```
<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

This way the user can print any page and it will always look good.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try printing a hidden view using advice given on :

http://morshed-alam.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-print-hidden-block-of-html-page.html

Answer (score 0):

As Randy Webb says in bytes.com: use a media stylesheet as in comp.infosystems.www.authoring.stylesheets.

However the printed version still shows in browser and user must press the print option in the menus